# Deadlock in the program when using for range on buffered channel

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I am learning Go and was playing with Goroutines and channels. I was writing a very contrived and naive workerpool using two buffered channels one for inputs and one for outputs.

Now I am closing my inputs channel after I add jobs to it and then reading the output channel finally to read the results from it, however when I used `for val := range ch` for the output program panics with a deadlock. Here is the sample code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    st := time.Now()

    jobs := make(chan int, 100)
    res := make(chan int, 100)

    // Putting items to the jobs channel
    for i := 0; i < 9; i++ {
        jobs <- i
    }
    close(jobs)

    go workerPool(jobs, res, 1)


    // This causes the program to panic with deadlock
    for v := range res {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }

// This works just fine and program does not panics
    //for i := 0; i < 9; i++ {
    //  fmt.Println(<-res)
    //}

    ed := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(ed.Sub(st))
}

func workerPool(ip <-chan int, op chan<- int, id int) {
    for v := range ip {
        fmt.Println("Worker", id, "working on ", v)
        op <- 1
    }
}
```

Here is the output I see

```
Worker 1 working on  0
Worker 1 working on  1
Worker 1 working on  2
Worker 1 working on  3
Worker 1 working on  4
Worker 1 working on  5
Worker 1 working on  6
Worker 1 working on  7
Worker 1 working on  8
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
```

I understand that when I use the conventional `for loop` I am fetching the exact number of values (9) which I initially put into `jobs` channel. But isn't `for range` supposed to handle this automatically that when there is no more data to be read from the channel, the channel will send the `false` value and the loop will terminate ?

Comment: The `range` operator will only terminate once the channel is closed. https://gobyexample.com/range-over-channels You might be confusing this with the behaviour of `select`, which will in fact evaluate `case`s of reading from closed channels.

Comment: "when there is no more data to be read from the channel" it will wait until there is; if it didn't, unbuffered channels wouldn't work at all. [Per the Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2), "sends and receives block until the other side is ready".

Comment: @Adrian as u can see this is a buffered channel, I know about unbuffered channels but the question is about buffered channel.

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you try to receive from an empty buffered channel, it still waits until there is data. If you try to send to a full buffered channel, it still waits until there is a consumer. Buffered channels are not significantly different from unbuffered channels. The behavior is exactly the same, but with a buffer.

Comment: The behavior is described on [the very next page of the Tour](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/3): "Sends to a buffered channel block only when the buffer is full. Receives block when the buffer is empty."

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this was pretty obvious, all I had to do was `close` the outputs channel in the worker and `range` started working correctly for obvious reasons.

```
func workerPool(ip <-chan int, op chan<- int, id int) {
    for v := range ip {
        fmt.Println("Worker", id, "working on ", v)
        op <- fib(v)
    }
    close(op) // change made 
}
```